# Consulta sql não funciona com data no Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi

estou fazendo a seguinte consulta no Delphi, usando MySQL:

```pascal
QueryExtraiDados.Close;
QueryExtraiDados.SQL.Clear;
QueryExtraiDados.SQL.Add('Select * from clientes where nascimento='+QuotedStr('%'+antecedencia+'%')+' ');
QueryExtraiDados.Open;
```

Não me retorna nada no Delphi, se eu rodar a seguinte consulta no MySQL:

```
Select * from clientes where nascimento='2015/05/26'
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Abs

Comment: Pessoal, já resolvi, ficou assim:
      QueryExtraiDados.Close;
  QueryExtraiDados.SQL.Clear;
  QueryExtraiDados.SQL.Add('Select * from clientes where nascimento='+QuotedStr(antecedencia)+' ');
  QueryExtraiDados.Open;

Comment: Renato, por favor, poste a sua solução como resposta, não em comentário. E como já resolveu o problema, aceite uma das respostas como a solução para sua pergunta. Pode ser a sua mesmo. Se outras respostas lhe ajudaram, vote nelas clicando na seta para cima, assim você incentiva as boas respostas. Abraço!

Answer (score 2):

Conforme [descrito no manual do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) segundo paragrafo:

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part. MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.

Ou seja:

O MySQL recupera e exibe valores DATE no formato `yyyy-mm-dd`. O intervalo suportado é `1000-01-01` a `9999-12-31`.

Desse modo a maneira correta da instruçao SQL seria:

```
select * from clientes where nascimento = '2015-05-26'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
QueryExtraiDados.Close;
QueryExtraiDados.SQL.Clear;

QueryExtraiDados.SQL.Add('Select * from clientes where    nascimento=:dtNasc');
QueryExtraiDados.Params[0].Value := FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd', antecedencia);
QueryExtraiDados.Open;
```

Só não lembro se é `Params`, `ParamByName`, mas é só tentar que vai dar certo, só um detalhe a variável antecedencia tem que ser do tipo `TDate` ou `TDateTime`.